# How do i change a timedelta object into seconds only in python 3.4?

Tags: python

I have a function in which I find the difference between two times as seen below

```
def speedCheck():
    from datetime import datetime
    T1 = input("At what time did the vehicle enter point A: ")
    T2 = input("At what time did the vehicle enter point B: ")
    Format = "%H:%M:%S"
    tdelta = datetime.strptime(T2, Format) - datetime.strptime(T1, Format)
    print(tdelta)

speedCheck()
```

I now have to find the average speed of the vehicle but to do so i need to calculate it as m/s then km/h from that by multiplying it by 3.6.
I have a set distance in meteres but need to convert my tdelta object (which is currently in HH:MM:SS) into seconds only in order to calculate the average speed.

Comment: You are relying on the `str()` conversion of `timedelta` objects. If that doesn't suite your needs, then simply extract the seconds for your own needs.

Comment: I don't want to extract the seconds, i wanted to change the minutes and/or hours into seconds so that i can add them to the original value for seconds. for example :00:01:03 would become 63

Comment: You misunderstand how timedelta objects work then; they *store* a count of days, seconds and microseconds. When you print them (or use `str()` on them, same thing), they are **formatted** to show the amount of time in days, hours, minutes, seconds and microseconds (with the first and last parts omitted if 0). You **already** have 63 seconds in your timedelta. Your problem is **how to format that information**.